# Mysql query performance slow using group by with aggregate count { >1 million users }

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-performance

**Query:**

```
select count(*) as col_0_0_, usertb0_.ACCT_STATUS_ID as col_1_0_, usertb0_.user_type as col_2_0_ 
from user_tbl usertb0_ 
inner join 
user_org_xref userorgxre1_ 
on usertb0_.USER_ID=userorgxre1_.USER_ID 
where 
(userorgxre1_.ORGANIZATION_ID in (2)) and (usertb0_.ACCT_STATUS_ID in (1 , 11 , 13 , 15 , 2)) 
group by usertb0_.ACCT_STATUS_ID , usertb0_.user_type;
```

**Tables & indexes:**

```
user_tbl ( PK: user_id) (Index: {user_id}, {ACCT_STATUS_ID},covered index:{ ACCT_STATUS_ID,user_type})
user_org_xref (pk: user_org_id, FK: user_id) (index {organization_id},{user_id})
```

Above query taking 20sec time to execute can anybody help me on it to improve performance

when parallel hits are more it was taking more than 30 sec's.

**Query Explain :**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you pls paste the results of the explain as well?

Comment: 2 things strike me where you may have room for improvement: swap the conditions in the where clause and use = instead of in() for the organisation_id criterion.

Comment: Thanks Shodow.. I tried conditions swap but it doesn't change

Comment: we have multiple organizations to input thats why i used "in" operator.                  Query Statistics Ref img : http://i64.tinypic.com/drb8td.png

Comment: Have you tried removing the `count` aggregation and the `group by`, to first test the general performance of the query, and compare it to the one you are doing now? That may help to find out which part of the query needs attention.

Comment: @DurgaMahesh in the code you provided there is only 1 organisation id listed.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: Are those tables in a many:1 relationship or what?

Comment: not many to 1 it is one to one relation (user_tbl <-> user_org_xref )

Comment: What happens if you drop all of the existing (non-primary) indexes, and replace them with two composite indexes (user_id,acct_status_id) and (user_id,organization_id)?

Comment: I`m guessing your WHERE condition returns more than a quarter of the data in all those JOINs so the optimizer chooses to ignore the index for such a large percentage of the data.

Answer (score 0):

The query plan in the EXPLAIN output is different from that in the diagram. The EXPLAIN plan does a range selection using the user_tbl.cc_uid_sts_type index (presumably this is on ACCT_STATUS_ID), from which it retrieves 481k rows. Then it joins to user_org_xref using the USER_ID_FK_idx index. If this does not include the organisation_id then adding this would be speed up performance.

The diagram plan uses the ORG_ID_FK index (on user_org_xref.organisation_id) to retrieve 499k rows. It then joins to user_tbl using the primary key index and thus filters the organisations users with the correct ACCT_STATUS_ID down to 249k rows.

Ultimately, whichever way you begin the query it is going to have to crunch a lot of data. There are nearly 500k users in the given organisation and a similar number of users with the correct ACCT_STATUS_ID. Thus if you really need the performance to improve you may need to denormalise in some way such as copying the ACCT_STATUS_ID to the user_org_xref table, although this is obviously a drastic solution that you would ideally want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I tried several approaches and actually, the best setup was forcing one index on each table of your query. It did the job in 4 seconds...

These are the indexes and the final query:

```
CREATE INDEX <index_name_1> ON user_tbl (acct_status_id, user_type, user_id);

CREATE INDEX <index_name_2> ON user_org_xref (organization_id, user_id);

SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS col_0_0_, 
  usertb0_.acct_status_id AS col_1_0_, 
  usertb0_.user_type AS col_2_0_ 
FROM user_tbl AS usertb0_ FORCE INDEX (<index_name_1>) 
INNER JOIN user_org_xref AS userorgxre1_ FORCE INDEX (<index_name_2>) ON 1=1
  AND userorgxre1_.user_id = usertb0_.user_id
WHERE 1=1
  AND userorgxre1_.organization_id IN (2)
  AND usertb0_.acct_status_id IN (1, 2, 11, 13, 15) 
GROUP BY 
  usertb0_.acct_status_id, 
  usertb0_.user_type
;
```